# Display fixed title when content comes into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Right now I have divs that show when you scroll past a certain mark but realized that this gets broken when the browser is resized. Is there any way I can make this responsive? I'm not sure if adding $(window).resize(checkY); would work either.

***EDIT:***
The end goal is to show the title when the associated content comes into view

HTML

```
 <div class="title" data-position="400,1150">Yama</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="1150,1800">Modurra</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="1800,2600">Computer</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="2600,3300">Maru</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="3300,3900">Sushi</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="3900,4700">Summit</div>
 <div class="title" data-position="4700,10000">Lights Out</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    //Note you do not need to make an anonymous
    //function just to do the call for checkY
    //just pass the function
    $(window).scroll(checkY);

    function checkY() {
        //save this value so we dont have to call the function everytime
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        console.log(top);
        $(".title").each(function () {
            var positionData = $(this).data("position").split(",");
            if (top > positionData[0] && top <= positionData[1]) {
                console.log("Show");
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                console.log("Hide");
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
    checkY();
</script>
```

EDIT

[image: info]

```
.title {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:45%;   
display:none;
padding:10px;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
color:#000;}
#Yama {

position:absolute;
display:block;
height:900px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:70pt; 
letter-spacing:0px; 
font-weight:100; 
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-align:center;}
```

This is the wrapper holding everything.

```
#mini {width:100%; height:100%;
padding-top:140px;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by broken? The elements still show up at the specified ranges. For instance the first div still shows up when page is between 400 and 1150 no matter how you resize the window. Or do you mean that 400 and 1150 are no longer a valid range after a resize?

Comment: It seems what you are wanting is to show a title when certain content is in the viewport is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yup! This was the only way I knew how to do it. Its a sort of "parallax" effect where different text will appear at a fixed location for a certain time and as you scroll the content above it, a new title will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is find the target content and determine if the element is within the viewport. If it is then you show the title.

With this you won't need to use data-* attributes. You can just put the title in the main content's element, and then use jQuery's [***.closest***](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method to get the closest parent (the content element). And from there do the tests.

HTML

```
<div id="Yama" class="content">
    <div class="title">Yama</div>
</div>
<div id="Modurra" class="content">
    <div class="title">Modurra</div>
</div>
<div id="Computer" class="content">
    <div class="title">Computer</div>
</div>
<div id="Maru" class="content">
    <div class="title">Maru</div>
</div>
<div id="Sushi" class="content">
    <div class="title">Sushi</div>
</div>
<div id="Summit" class="content">
    <div class="title">Sushi</div>
</div>
<div id="LightsOut" class="content">
    <div class="title">Lights Out</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(checkY);

function checkY(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".title").each(function(){
       var target = $(this).closest(".content");

       //The start range value is just offset().top
       var tTop = target.offset().top;

       //The end range value is the start range value plus 
       //the content elements height
       var tBottom = tTop+target.outerHeight();

       if(top >= tTop && top <= tBottom){
           console.log("Show"); 
           $(this).show(); 
       } else {
           console.log("Hide"); 
           $(this).hide();
       }       
    });
}
checkY();
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/rAU46/)

Comment: Can I offset the from the closest parent? Right now the text appears the moment the top of the container hits the top of the viewport. Can I make it so that the title is triggered the moment a div (in this case wrapper) hit the top? Please see the orig post, I added a picture that should help!